# Integrating a twice differentiable function

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $f = f(x,y) \in C^2(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})$ and $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\,\partial y} > 0$. Then for $(a,b)\times(c,d) \in \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, we have

\begin{equation}
0 < \int_c^d \int_a^b \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \, \partial y} \, dx \, dy = f(b,d) - f(b,c) - f(a,d) + f(a,c).
\end{equation}

Now suppose we are in higher dimensions and $f \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n)$ with $\det \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial y_j} > 0$. What I would like to be able to conclude is similar to the $1$D problem: that for some $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (unrelated to previous $a,b,c,d$)
\begin{equation}
0 < f(b,d) - f(b,c) - f(a,d) + f(a,c).
\end{equation}
I would like to be able to conclude this from the fact that $\det \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \, \partial y_j} > 0$, so there are linearly independent vectors $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $u^t\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \, \partial y_j} v > 0$. Then perhaps by integrating over a region in the $uv$-plane we can have something like
\begin{equation}
0 < \int_{?}^{?}\int_{?}^{?}?? = f(b,d) - f(b,c) - f(a,d) + f(a,c).
\end{equation}
But I seem to be stuck in the details (assuming the desired conclusion is true).

Apologies in advance - I wish I was able to formulate the question in a more precise way!

Comment: If $n$ is even, the determinant of $\det \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial y_j}  $ is the same for $f$ and $-f$. But the inequality you want changes sign with the reversal of the sign of $f$. Also, now that there is no order of $a,b$, they can be exchanged, reversing the sign of $f(b,d) - f(b,c) - f(a,d) + f(a,c)$. And you say for **some** $a,b,c,d$, not for all. So, it seems you are just trying to rule out the case that $f(b,d) - f(b,c) - f(a,d) + f(a,c)$ is  identically zero?

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat Yes, you are right, that is essentially what I would like to conclude here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in the vector  case ($n>1$) there is no preferred order of $a,b$, they can be exchanged, reversing the sign of $f(b,d) - f(b,c) - f(a,d) + f(a,c)$. And since you want the inequality  for **some** $a,b,c,d$, the only thing to do is  to rule out the case that $f(b,d) - f(b,c) - f(a,d) + f(a,c)$ is  identically zero.

Suppose that 
$$f(b,d) - f(b,c) - f(a,d) + f(a,c)=0,\qquad \forall \ a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}^n\tag{1}$$
Fix $a,b\in \mathbb{R}^n$,  $i,j\in \{1,\dots,n\}$ and consider the function $g(s,t) = f(a+se_i, b+te_j)$ where $e_i, e_j$ are  elements of the standard basis. By $(1)$, it satisfies 
$$g(s,t) - g(s,0) - g(0,t) + g(0,0)=0,\qquad \forall s,t\in\mathbb{R}$$
Considering the second-order Taylor expansion of $g$ at $(0,0)$, we find that 
$$
\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial s\partial t}(0,0) = 0
$$
In terms of $f$, this means 
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial y_j} \equiv 0
$$
That is, $\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial y_j} \right)$ is the zero matrix.

Comment: With the second-order Taylor expansion of $g$ at $(0,0)$ and Lagrange remainder, I find that $s^2(\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial s^2}(\lambda s, \lambda t) - \frac{\partial^2g}{\partial s^2}(\lambda s, 0)) + t^2(\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial t^2}(\lambda s, \lambda t) - \frac{\partial^2g}{\partial t^2}(0, \lambda t)) + st\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial s\partial t}(\lambda s, \lambda t) = 0$ where $\lambda \in (0,1)$. Am I correct in letting now $s = t \to 0$ to obtain $\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial s\partial t}(0, 0) = 0$?

Comment: I don't recognize what you wrote as a Taylor expansion at $(0,0)$. That expansion would have derivatives evaluated at $(0,0)$ only. The result would be that the only surviving derivative after cancellation is the mixed second-order.

Comment: But in order to truncate to second order, isn't the Lagrange remainder needed? (which is why the second derivatives are evaluated at some point $(\lambda s, \lambda t)$ between $(0,0)$ and $(s,t)$).

Comment: I had the Peano form of remainder in mind. That is, the second order polynomial plus something smaller.